# JavaScript Link Extractor

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, extract, web-crawler

I am interested in extracting links from sites where the links are dynamically generated with JavaScript and are essentially invisible in HTML source. For instance here  is an example site where the links are inserted via a js menu:
http://www.stcroixwebsolutions.com/

When I hover with the mouse over the links, I see the links, but they are not discernible in HTML source.

I would like to output the links like so:
http://www.stcroixwebsolutions.com/?110000
http://www.stcroixwebsolutions.com/?110010
etc.

What do you recommend I use to extract these links?

Comment: Are you trying to store the actual URL within that ?### number ?

Comment: Did you forgot that StackOverflow can recognize URLs without the `[]`? AFAIR, it uses the same library like the one Reddit use. Just use that for URL recognition function. As for link-like behaviour element, that can be easily done with `SPAN` element, CSS rules and `ONCLICK` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this... This will at least get you started!

http://jsfiddle.net/Qv4St/

```
function showLinks() {

  var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
  var last = links.length;
  var list = {};

  // for each anchor...
  for (var i = 0; i < last; i++) {

    list[links[i].href] = i;
    console.log(list);
    //' - text=' + links[i].innerHTML + '<br>';

}

  var linksList = document.getElementById( 'linksList' );
  linksList.innerHTML = list;
}    ​
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var getLinks = function () {
        "use strict";
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
            b = a.length,
            c = 0,
            d = [],
            e = "",
            f = location.href;
        f = f.substring(0, f.lastIndexOf("/"));
        for (c = 0; c < b; c += 1) {
            e = a[c].getAttribute("href");
            if (typeof e === "string" && e.length > 4) {
                if (e.charAt(0) === "/" || e.charAt(0) === "?") {
                    e = f + e;
                }
                d.push(e);
            }
        }
        return d.join("\n") + "\n" + d.length + " total links";
    },
    myLinks = getLinks(); //myLinks variable will contain the desired output.
//To output to the console just replace the line with 'return' with this code:
//console.log(d.join("\n") + "\n" + d.length + " total links");
```

Run this code to return a list of all hyperlinks on the given page in a list with each result on its own line.

EDIT:  I now convert relative links to absolute URIs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard [document.links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection that is all the links in a document. Simply iterate over that.